# How to get posts by multiple post slugs?

Tags: posts, wp-query, slug

i am trying to get posts by multiple posts slugs, i can do this by passing post ids but I do not want to pass post ids i am looking for posts slug

Here is my code

```
$option = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'post',
'name' => 'berlin, frankfurt, munich, augsburg'
);

$new_query = new WP_Query($option);
if ($new_query->have_posts()) {
while ($new_query->have_posts()) {
$new_query->the_post();
/* my html stuff */
}
}
```

but it does not display anything but when i pass only "berlin" then queyr gives me correct results. it mean i only need to use post ids to get selected multiple posts ?

Comment: When in doubt, it's always good to check the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) on `WP_Query`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to put your post slugs in an array for the `post_name__in` parameter:

```
'post_name__in' => [ 'berlin', 'frankfurt', 'munich', 'augsburg' ],
```